# Mysql fulltext column

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

i have users table  with first_name, last_name columns

These are my records:

```
Ramiz,Murtaza
Ramiz,Murtaza
Murtaza,Ramiz
Xyz,Ramiz
Xyz,Murtaza
Claude Powlowski,Prof. Francesco Osinski V
Xyz,Ramiz
Ramiz,Murtaza
Jordon Stoltenberg IV,Prof. Kyle Cummerata
Conor Shields MD,Darien Murray
Murtaza,Ramiz
Jarrett Goyette I,Mr. Dejon Jenkins MD
Kadin Connelly,Walter McGlynn
Guillermo Waters,Lexus Jast
Murtaza,Xyz
Laron Schimmel,Allan Hoppe MD
Prof. Grover Trantow,Stuart Muller
Ramiz,Xyz
Ed Spencer,Haleigh DuBuque
Ramiz,Xyz
```

i am going to search Ramiz Murtaza
and i  need sorting as following:

Ramiz Murtaza (on top all related Ramiz Murtaza) then
Murtaza Ramiz (all)  then
Ramiz Xyz (all) then
Murtaza Xyz (all) then
Xyz Ramiz (all) then
Xyz Murtaza (all)

Answer (score 0):

You will need something resembling

```
SELECT *, MATCH(`name`) AGAINST 'Ramiz Murtaza' AS `relevance`
WHERE MATCH(`name`) AGAINST 'Ramiz Murtaza' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
ORDER BY `relevance` DESC
```